# Azure Active Directory B2C not deserializing httpContext.Session in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I successfully got the github sample "active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi" working with my own Tenant and the Azure Active Directory B2C. It is working as expected.  When I create my own MVC project from scratch and replicate every single thing down to the exact same dll's, it fails to reproduce the same results as the sample. It fails when trying to Deserialize the HttpContext.Session within the MSALSessoCache Class, Load method.

I can see that I am getting the token back with the proper information and claims when in the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived. It also reflects in the portals audit logs as success. When stepping through the code, the deserialization results in a null object exception when casting to blob. I can see the user info and the fact that it works in the sample, I am assuming the Azure Tenant is correct.

I created the new .net 4.7.2 MVC application with "No Authentication" , changed to HTTPS as well as updated the Project Url in properties. I copied the code over verifying the OWIN Startup.cs class and Startup.Auth.cs. Everything is identical with exception to the https redirect url and https TaskServiceUrl within the web.config... even the exact same versions of the dll's. I have also verified that the proper https url have been added in the tenants application setup with Azure B2C. I am at a loss.

Comment: Could you share some more detail information or screenshot about your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some assistance, we figured out that downgrading the Microsoft.Identity.Client dll to 1.1.0.0 prerelease did the trick. I know that 1.1.4.0 and 2.0.0 does **not** work. Can't say whether 1.1.1.0, 1.1.2.0 or 1.1.3.0 works or not. Thanks asmithKinegdo